# Parse HTML and build a map from the parsed value using clojure

Tags: html, clojure

I am using enlive clojure to parse HTML. My parser looks like;

```
(def each-rows
  (for [tr crawl-page
        :let [row (html/select tr [:td (attr= :class "bl_12")])]
        :when (seq row)]
    row))
```

which extracts result as following;

```
  {:tag :a,
   :attrs
   {:class "bl_12",
    :href
    "url1"},
   :content ("Chapter 1")}
  {:tag :a,
   :attrs
   {:class "bl_12",
    :href
    "url2"},
   :content ("Chapter 2")}
  {:tag :a,
   :attrs
   {:class "bl_12",
    :href
    "url3"},
   :content ("Chapter 3")}
```

Now my objective is to get a dictionary like this;

```
   {:Chapter_1 "url1"  
   :Chapter_2 "url2"
   :Chapter_3 "url3"}
```

I managed to write a method which extracts only href or only content, but couldn't make it as a map

```
 (defn read-specific-other [x]
  (map (comp second :attrs) x))
```

output : `[:href "url1"]`

```
  (defn read-specific-content [x]
    (map (comp first ::content) x))
```

(map read-specific-content each-rows)

output :

```
(("Chapter 1"
"Chapter 2"
"Chapter 3"
))
```

How do I get the desired result

Comment: Hi, I am considering using Clojure to parse XML. Did you choose Clojure because (a) it is more efficient or (b) it is the language you just use?

Comment: I am working on crawling and data processing & clojure is very powerful and natural to do such things, pipeline is super efficient (Thread macro) , I choosed clojure for its natural power of data processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `zipmap`

```
(zipmap (read-specific-other each-rows) (read-specific-content each-rows))
```

If you really want the keys to be keywords, then use the `keyword` function; but I recommend keeping strings as the keys.

Also consider using an `into for` pattern instead:

```
(into {}
  (for [[{:keys [attrs]} {:keys [content]}] rows]
    [content attrs]))
```